# How to open emacs gui/ide from mac terminal?

Tags: macos, user-interface, emacs, ide, terminal

I'm trying to open files up on emacs outside of the terminal.  I prefer a gui/ide environment when I code instead of doing it through a terminal.  I initially thought that typing `emacs filename.py` would open that file through Emacs.app, however it only allowed me to edit the file through the terminal.  When this didn't work, I looked into editing the .profile and .emacs files in my home directory but this was to no avail.

Maybe this is more intuitive than what I've read but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I thought emacs was a terminal editor...can I not use emacs inside the terminal?

Comment: Yes, you can use emacs inside the terminal. However, emacs can also be used as an ide outside of the terminal and at the time of asking this question, that's what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming you have Emacs installed from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) like this:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

Just type the following command to open Emacs.app from terminal:

```
open -a Emacs filename.py
```

If you want all files opened in the same frame, instead of new frames, put this into your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

Comment: Update on the issue.  I didn't use homebrew to install emacs, I grabbed it from [link][www.emacsforosx.com].  However, i just tried `open -a Emacs filename.py` and it worked.  It opened the Emacs ide window and filename.py in a seperate Emacs window.  Call me picky though, what whould I have to do if I wanted the command `emacs filename.py` to do the same thing?  This may be what @shosti was getting at getting at with the emacsclient. Thanks @katspaugh, @qaphla, and @shosti!

Comment: Since I've been living with katspaugh's suggestion, I'm marking this answered.

Comment: Does this still work?  When I use `open -a Emacs filename.py` I get `Unable to find application named 'Emacs'`.  I also tried lowercase `emacs` but get the same result.  I did install emacs using Homebrew as @katspaugh mentioned.  The command `which emacs` returns `/usr/local/bin/emacs` (I also tried putting this after the `-a` but that does not work either).  I want to avoid opening a duplicate question if not necessary.

Comment: @stvn66 have you added `--cocoa` to the install command? Can you run the GUI Emacs app if you click on its icon? If you can't find the icon, install with the `--cocoa` flag. Also try running `brew linkapps emacs`.

Comment: @katspaugh, I don't think I used `--cocoa` originally but tried to re-install it with that and it simply said emacs was up to date.  I just removed then re-installed emacs using that flag (I was given the warning that `--cocoa was deprecated; using --with-cocoa instead!`).  After doing this I can open files in their own window (and the meta key works!).  Thank you!

Comment: brew linkapps is also deprecated

Comment: I thought emacs was a terminal editor...can I not use emacs inside the terminal?

Comment: @CharlieParker you definitely can, but the standalone GUI version is by far better.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to open files in Emacs from the terminal is the `emacsclient` command, which will open the file in your existing Emacs app (preventing startup time). If you're on OSX and you installed Emacs through Homebrew, the `emacsclient` binary will already be set up. (In your Emacs config, you have to include `(server-start)` somewhere.)

If you actually want to spin up a new GUI app instance instead, you can set up your own shell script and put it in your `PATH` somewhere before the existing `emacs` binary. It sounds like you're using Homebrew, which sets up the `emacs` binary as the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw  "$@"
```

The `-nw` is what prevents Emacs from opening in GUI mode. You can make your own `emacs` shell script and leave out `-nw`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

Comment: I second the `emacsclient` recommendation. Aliased it with `e` and happy ever since.

Answer (score 6):

To do what you want, you'd need to find the location of the actual binary contained in Emacs.app, and use that as the command instead of emacs. Most likely, it's at

```
/path/to/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

Which, if you have Emacs.app in your Applications folder, as would be typical, would be

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

To set it up with a shorter command to use, you could try adding to your .profile (I don't know what shell you use) the following line, or whatever equivalent it has for your shell (This works for bash and zsh, at least):

```
alias emacsgui='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs'
```

Answer (score 5):

The modern way to go about this is by installing Emacs using [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask):

```
brew cask install emacs
```

Source: [this comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36190#issuecomment-457099290) by Homebrew project leader Mike McQuaid, which reads:

> Cocoa support for Emacs will not be accepted. This is provided by `brew cask install emacs`.

Answer (score 2):

One should link emacs to /Applications if not already done,

```
brew linkapps emacs
```

to link the emacs to symlink emacs installed in Cellar. Once symlinked, you can open emacs by

```
open -a emacs
```

as already pointed out by @katspaugh

Answer (score 0):

brew doesn't have cask command anymore.
I used `brew install emacs` and I can find Emacs app installed in my application directory.
You can also head to https://emacsformacosx.com and download the .dmg file.